# How do I open VS2013 NODEJS projects in VS2015?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

I wanted to load some VS2013 NODEJS Console (Typescript) projects into the new version of VS2015.  This was the error message..

[image]

"The Project Types may not be installed" indicates that VS2015, by default does not appear to be able to handle NODEJS console (Typescript) projects.  Do I need to install NTVS for VS2015?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the answer is yes, you must load the NTVS package (Manually) which you can find at [CodePlex](https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/releases/view/614706)... Make sure you close all instances of VS first...

[image]